# GNU smalltalk run an .st file

Tags: gnu-smalltalk

I am following the Account class in the GNU smalltalk documation. I have a image with the Account class added. I have tested the loading of an .st file using gst -I xxx.im file.st. But cannot make a := Account from a line in the file.st and print to prove the Account has been made. I am trying to use the file.st as a series of instructions ie. deposit etc Thanks.

Comment: Please put more effort in describing your question. Otherwise it is too difficult to make sense of it.